# How to make a perfect bash wrapper script

Tags: linux, bash

I need to make a bash script to replace a certain application.
Script should do some work and then execute said application in a way that everything (parameters both positional and named, env variables, signals etc.) will work as if it was the original application executed.

My idea was to do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do something custom
export PATH=/some/custom/override:$PATH

# Execute the original script
exec php8.1 $@
```

Is this enough or should I do something else to ensure a perfect substitution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check your scripts with shellcheck .

```
Line 7:
exec php8.1 $@
            ^-- SC2068 (error): Double quote array expansions to avoid re-splitting elements.
```

Use:

```
exec php8.1 "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

- If PATH is empty or unset, your code adds an empty path entry (after `:`), causing the current directory to always be in PATH.
- You should set PATH like: `export PATH=/my/path${PATH+:$PATH}`, or `export PATH=/my/path${PATH:+:$PATH}`.
- The first one avoids an empty entry if PATH is unset, but *not* if it has already been set to empty. The second one always avoids an empty PATH entry.
- Although it's unlikely PATH will be unset or empty, if you want "perfect substitution", you should use the first example. If you believe empty PATH is always a bug for your application, you could use the second example.
- Apart from that, `exec command "$@"` is pretty standard (add quotes as already mentioned).